# Default text for the shell read command?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

Basically I want default input that the user can edit if necessary. Eg:

```
Please enter the city: Toronto
```

where "Toronto" is the default text and the user can actually delete it and enter another city.

Edit: I'm using bash 3.2 on OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's the *bash* shell – and a recent version of *bash*:

```
read -e -p "Please enter the city: " -i "Toronto" REPLY
```

Comment: Super! Works on Debian. Does not work in OS X ML. How to do it on Mac?

Comment: @user151851 You can install Bash 4.x with package managers such as [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/).

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which shell you are using.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -p "Enter a town: " -e -i Toronto TOWN
echo $TOWN
```

Example stolen from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479987/suggest-answer-to-user-input-in-bash-scripting